# Angular unit test EventEmitter that is inside an Observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I am trying to unit test a function called `insert(e)` that takes an event and inserts an uploaded image into the application's catalog. The function parses the event to get the file that was uploaded and uses an Observable to emit the data. Here is the insert function:

```
insert(e: Event) {
    ...
    Observable.forkJoin(subjects$).subscribe(res => {
      res = res.filter(g => g);
      if (res.length) {
        this.updateToolbox.emit({ add: res });
      }
    });
  }
```

**Note**: **...** refers to code that handles parsing and building of the `subjects$`

Here is my component spec file:

```
  it('should insert into catalog', () => {
    const updateToolboxSpy = spyOn(catalog.updateToolbox, 'emit');
    let file = new File([''], 'testfile.svg', {type: 'image/svg+xml'});
    file = new File([file.slice(0, file.size), '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" '
    + 'xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" '
    + 'width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 505.922 505.922" style="enable-background:new '
    + '0 0 505.922 505.922;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">↵<g>↵  <g>↵        '
    + '<path d="M442.68,31.622h-18.182C423.887,14.07,409.564,0,391.859,0c-17.699,0-32.02,14.07-32.631,31.622H63.24    '
    + 'c-26.193,0-47.43,21.236-47.43,47.43v379.44c0,26.193,21.236,47.43,47.43,47.43H442.68c26.195,0,47.432-21.236,47.432-47.43    '
    + 'V79.052C490.111,52.858,468.875,31.622,442.68,31.622z M67.757,106.158c0-12.473,10.11-22.583,22.583-22.583h72.277    '
    + 'c12.472,0,22.583,10.11,22.583,22.583s-10.11,22.583-22.583,22.583H90.34C77.874,128.74,67.757,118.63,67.757,106.158z     '
    + 'M252.96,449.459c-77.338,0-140.032-62.693-140.032-140.031c0-77.339,62.693-140.032,140.032-140.032    '
    + 's140.032,62.693,140.032,140.032C392.992,386.766,330.299,449.459,252.96,449.459z"/>↵      '
    + '<circle cx="252.96" cy="309.427" r="81.31"/>↵    </g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵'
    + '</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵<g>↵</g>↵</svg>'], file.name);

    const e: any = {
      preventDefault: jasmine.createSpy('prevent'),
      target: {
        blur: jasmine.createSpy('blur'),
        value: 'abc',
        files: [file]
      }
    };
    catalog.insert(e);
    // getting called before the event gets emitted
    // expect(updateToolboxSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    /*Using setTimeout works */
    setTimeout(function() {
      expect(updateToolboxSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }, 5000);
  });
```

The code above works, but I don't want to use `setTimeout` and wonder if there is an *angular* or *js* or *jasmine* way to properly expect that the EventEmitter was called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Angular provides an `async` function that will consume a test and wait for any asynchronous operations to complete before finishing the test.

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'

...

describe('a test', async() => {

  expect('some async thing').toWork();

});
```

There's other ways to work with async testing, some of which are recommended by Jasmine and other Angular testing functions. Check out the docs [here.](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service)